# d3 label are overlaping

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a d3 pie chart. Everything is working fine but my label is overlapping. I have tried to fix it using CSS, but it's not working.
HTML code is below

```
<div class="custom-chart"></div>
```

JS look like this

```
var details = [{ "name": "GRAND DING HOUSE Hong Kong HK", "label": "72" }, { "name": "MI-NE SUSHI HONG KONG HK", "label": "10" }, { "name": "TNS INVESTMENT LIMITED", "label": "6" }, { "name": "GRAND DING HOUSE Hong Kong HK", "label": "2" }, { "name": "MI-NE SUSHI HONG KONG HK", "label": "1" }, { "name": "Other", "label": "9" }];
chartScript(details, '.custom-chart'); 
function chartScript(details, clsName) {
    var lblName = new Array(6); var i = 0;
    for (var index in details) {
        lblName[i] = details[index];
        i++;
    }
    var width = 350, height = 350;
    let colors = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(lblName).range(['#A4A4A4', '#0073AA', '#009DD9', '#005D87', '#00A76D', '#6DC067']);
    let svg = d3.select(clsName).append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
    let data = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {return d.label;})(details);
    let segments = d3.arc().innerRadius(55).outerRadius(120).padAngle(0.05).padRadius(30);
    let sections = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(175,145)').selectAll('path').data(data);
    sections.enter().append('path').attr('d', segments).attr('fill', function (d, i) {return colors(i);});
    let content = d3
        .select(clsName)
        .select('g')
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(data);
    content
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .classed('inside', true)
        .each(function (d) {
            let center = segments.centroid(d);
            d3.select(this)
                    .attr('x', center[0] - 10)
                    .attr('y', center[1])
                    .text(d.data.label + '%');
        });
    let legends = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(30, 270)').selectAll('.legends').data(data);
    let legend = legends.enter().append('g').classed('legends', true).attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            if (i < 3) {return 'translate(0,' + (i + 1) * 20 + ')';} 
            else { return 'translate(170,' + (i - 3 + 1) * 20 + ')'; }
        });
    legend.append('rect').attr('width', 10).attr('height', 10).attr('fill', function (d, i) {return colors(i);})
        .attr('x', -20)
        .attr('y', 0);
    legend.append('text').classed('label', true).text(function (d) {return d.data.name;}).attr('fill', function (d, i) {return colors(i); }).attr('x', 15).attr('y', 10);
}
```

This is my chart screenshot which is showing the overlapping label. The right side label is also not showing.

[image]

Comment: In the line 'translate(170,' + (i - 3 + 1) * 20 + ')' 

replace 170 with, say, 250... should be working

Answer (score 1):

You need to make couple of changes in the d3 code to overcome overlapping.

1) Increase the width of SVG.

2) Translate pie chart to the center of SVG.

3) Also translate the legend group towards right.

Please find attached updated code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-chart"></div>
    <script>
        var details = [{ "name": "GRAND DING HOUSE Hong Kong HK", "label": "72" }, { "name": "MI-NE SUSHI HONG KONG HK", "label": "10" }, { "name": "TNS INVESTMENT LIMITED", "label": "6" }, { "name": "GRAND DING HOUSE Hong Kong HK", "label": "2" }, { "name": "MI-NE SUSHI HONG KONG HK", "label": "1" }, { "name": "Other", "label": "9" }];
chartScript(details, '.custom-chart'); 
function chartScript(details, clsName) {
    var lblName = new Array(6); var i = 0;
    for (var index in details) {
        lblName[i] = details[index];
        i++;
    }
    var rectWidth = 650;
    var width = rectWidth, height = 350;
    let colors = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(lblName).range(['#A4A4A4', '#0073AA', '#009DD9', '#005D87', '#00A76D', '#6DC067']);
    let svg = d3.select(clsName).append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
    let data = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {return d.label;})(details);
    let segments = d3.arc().innerRadius(55).outerRadius(120).padAngle(0.05).padRadius(30);
    let sections = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate('+rectWidth/2+',145)').selectAll('path').data(data);
    sections.enter().append('path').attr('d', segments).attr('fill', function (d, i) {return colors(i);});
    let content = d3
        .select(clsName)
        .select('g')
        .selectAll('text')
        .data(data);
    content
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .classed('inside', true)
        .each(function (d) {
            let center = segments.centroid(d);
            d3.select(this)
                    .attr('x', center[0] - 10)
                    .attr('y', center[1])
                    .text(d.data.label + '%');
        });
    let legends = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(30, 270)').selectAll('.legends').data(data);
    let legend = legends.enter().append('g').classed('legends', true).attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            if (i < 3) {return 'translate(0,' + (i + 1) * 20 + ')';} 
            else { return 'translate('+rectWidth/2+',' + (i - 3 + 1) * 20 + ')'; }
        });
    legend.append('rect').attr('width', 10).attr('height', 10).attr('fill', function (d, i) {return colors(i);})
        .attr('x', -20)
        .attr('y', 0);
    legend.append('text').classed('label', true).text(function (d) {return d.data.name;})
    .attr('fill', function (d, i) {return colors(i); }).attr('x', 15).attr('y', 10);
}
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```